# Hide dots indica

Tags: swiftui

I've searching for this answer and realized there was no content on Internet (or i couldn't find it). Finally I figured it out so I'm here to share the response of this answer.

How to pass from this:

[image: TabView pager with dots indicator]

To this:

[image: TabView pager with no dots indicator]

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add `.page(indexDisplayMode: .never)` in the `.tabViewStyle` constructor like this:

```
       TabView(selection: $selection){
            Text("ORDER")
                .tag(TicketDetailViewPages.ORDER)
            Text("ORIGINAL")
                .tag(TicketDetailViewPages.ORIGINAL)
            Text("PRIZES")
                .tag(TicketDetailViewPages.PRIZES)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
```